# Draw Image using CYMK values

Tags: java, rgb, bufferedimage, cmyk, image-conversion

I want to convert a buffered image from RGBA format to CYMK format without using auto conversion tools or libraries,so i tried to extract the RGBA values from individual pixels that i got using `BufferedImage.getRGB()` and here what I've done so far :

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage("image path")
int R,G,B,pixel,A;
float Rc,Gc,Bc,K,C,M,Y;
int height = img.getHeight();
int width = img.getWidth();
    for(int y = 0 ; y < height ; y++){
        for(int x = 0 ; x < width ; x++){
            pixel = img.getRGB(x, y);

            //I shifted the int bytes to get RGBA values
            A = (pixel>>24)&0xff;
            R = (pixel>>16)&0xff;
            G = (pixel>>8)&0xff;
            B = (pixel)&0xff;
            Rc = (float) ((float)R/255.0);
            Gc = (float) ((float)G/255.0);
            Bc = (float) ((float)B/255.0);

            // Equations i found on the internet to get CYMK values
            K = 1 - Math.max(Bc, Math.max(Rc, Gc));
            C = (1- Rc - K)/(1-K);
            Y = (1- Bc - K)/(1-K);
            M = (1- Gc - K)/(1-K);                                
        }
    }
```

Now after I've extracted it ,i want to draw or construct an image using theses values ,can you tell me of a method or a way to do this because i don't think`BufferedImage.setRGB()` would work ,and also when i printed the values of `C,Y,M` some of them had`NaN` value can someone tell me what that means and how to deal with it ?

Comment: In how far should the resulting image be different from the input? (Vaguely, I'd expect that you'd have to convert the CMYK values back to RGB, because RGB is simply the way how the image is stored in memory. But that wouldn't make sense. Otherwise, you *might* have to dive deeply into `ColorSpace` and related classes (and they can be ugly if you're not deeply familiar with the subject...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible, converting RGB to CMYK without a proper color profile will not produce the best results. For better performance and higher color fidelity, I really recommend using an ICC color profile (see `ICC_Profile` and `ICC_ColorSpace` classes) and [`ColorConvertOp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html). :-)

Anyway, here's how to do it using your own conversion. The important part is creating a CMYK color space, and a `ColorModel` and `BufferedImage` using that color space (you could also load a CMYK color space from an ICC profile as mentioned above, but the colors would probably look more off, as it uses different calculations than you do).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(args[0]));
    int height = img.getHeight();
    int width = img.getWidth();

    // Create a color model and image in CMYK color space (see custom class below)
    ComponentColorModel cmykModel = new ComponentColorModel(CMYKColorSpace.INSTANCE, false, false, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
    BufferedImage cmykImg = new BufferedImage(cmykModel, cmykModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(width, height), cmykModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
    WritableRaster cmykRaster = cmykImg.getRaster();

    int R,G,B,pixel;
    float Rc,Gc,Bc,K,C,M,Y;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            pixel = img.getRGB(x, y);

            // Now, as cmykImg already is in CMYK color space, you could actually just invoke
            //cmykImg.setRGB(x, y, pixel);
            // and the method would perform automatic conversion to the dest color space (CMYK)

            // But, here you go... (I just cleaned up your code a little bit):
            R = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
            G = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
            B = (pixel) & 0xff;

            Rc = R / 255f;
            Gc = G / 255f;
            Bc = B / 255f;

            // Equations I found on the internet to get CMYK values
            K = 1 - Math.max(Bc, Math.max(Rc, Gc));
            if (K == 1f) {
                // All black (this is where you would get NaN values I think)
                C = M = Y = 0;
            }
            else { 
                C = (1- Rc - K)/(1-K);
                M = (1- Gc - K)/(1-K);
                Y = (1- Bc - K)/(1-K);
            }

            // ...and store the CMYK values (as bytes in 0..255 range) in the raster
            cmykRaster.setDataElements(x, y, new byte[] {(byte) (C * 255), (byte) (M * 255), (byte) (Y * 255), (byte) (K * 255)});
        }
    }

    // You should now have a CMYK buffered image
    System.out.println("cmykImg: " + cmykImg);
}

// A simple and not very accurate CMYK color space
// Full source at https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/imageio/imageio-core/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/color/CMYKColorSpace.java
final static class CMYKColorSpace extends ColorSpace {

    static final ColorSpace INSTANCE = new CMYKColorSpace();

    final ColorSpace sRGB = getInstance(CS_sRGB);

    private CMYKColorSpace() {
        super(ColorSpace.TYPE_CMYK, 4);
    }

    public static ColorSpace getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public float[] toRGB(float[] colorvalue) {
        return new float[]{
                (1 - colorvalue[0]) * (1 - colorvalue[3]),
                (1 - colorvalue[1]) * (1 - colorvalue[3]),
                (1 - colorvalue[2]) * (1 - colorvalue[3])
        };
    }

    public float[] fromRGB(float[] rgbvalue) {
        // NOTE: This is essentially the same equation you use, except 
        // this is slightly optimized, and values are already in range [0..1]

        // Compute CMY
        float c = 1 - rgbvalue[0];
        float m = 1 - rgbvalue[1];
        float y = 1 - rgbvalue[2];

        // Find K
        float k = Math.min(c, Math.min(m, y));

        // Convert to CMYK values
        return new float[]{(c - k), (m - k), (y - k), k};
    }

    public float[] toCIEXYZ(float[] colorvalue) {
        return sRGB.toCIEXYZ(toRGB(colorvalue));
    }

    public float[] fromCIEXYZ(float[] colorvalue) {
        return sRGB.fromCIEXYZ(fromRGB(colorvalue));
    }
}
```

---

PS: Your question talks about RGBA and CMYK, but your code just ignores the alpha value, so I did the same. If you really wanted to, you could just keep the alpha value as-is and have a CMYK+A image, to allow alpha-compositing in CMYK color space. I'll leave that as an exercise. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for this well explained answer!!.

Comment: After i set the data elements in the `cmykRaster` ,does it automatically affect the `cmykImg` ?or do i have to write another statement?

Comment: @Makdous Yes, any changes to the raster will also affect the image (roughly speaking, the raster is the pixels of the image, without the color information).  You don’t need to do anything else.